# App for designing server farm

Tags: deployment, diagrams, server-farm

I was wondering. Is there an app for designing server farm layouts? I know that this can be achieved using UML designer apps or Visio but I was looking for something more specialised on this particular part of a startup deployment. An app for designing the relationships between servers and their scopes would be very helpful.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!